# How ffmpeg does mpegts streaming?

Tags: ffmpeg

Here's how I stream MPEG-TS to a relay using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -re -i out.ts -f mpegts -vcodec copy -acodec copy http://localhost:8081/secret
```

My question is in the internals of ffmpeg, I want to understand the core process as to how ffmpeg stream *mpegts*, what it does to the file to stream it, does it manipulate the byte it streams or it just stream as-is?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the transport stream is parsed, the audio and video elementary streams are read and depacketized. They are then repacketized, and remuxed into a new transport stream, then sent over http.

If you changed containers, the elementary streams may be converted  to slightly different format depending on the codec and container global headers before being remuxed.

And if you transcoded the elementary stream would have been converted to raw pixels, and PCM, the reencoded back to a new elementary stream.